# Postgres Installed in Linux (RHEL) and trying to access / connect using pgadmin (Windows)

Tags: installation, postgresql-9.4, redhat

I've installed and configured postgresql in Linux successfully,

```
1. postgres user created
2. new db created successfully
3. I'm trying to connect using pgadmin III (Windows)
4. Following details are adding in pgadmin window

Host: DEMO
Host: XXXX
Port: 5432
Maintenance DB: postgres
Username: postgres
password: G0!mf17.

5. Clicked on OK
```

It's tried to connect and displayed message connecting to database.... Failed.

I'm not sure why it's failed and what needs to configure in linux system.

I'm new to linux, If anyone able to guide me solve this issue it will be greatful.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error message contains more information than just "Failed". Please edit your question and add the **exact** error message.

Comment: I'm not sure where to check for error message, can you please guide me?

Comment: Did you configure that postgres listens on the right IP address and that it accepts the IP address of you windows computer?

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this.. I've really dont know what's need to be done

Comment: Perhaps start by reading the manual on how to configure Postgres. This way you either solve the problem yourself or you are able to ask more specific questions.

Comment: I've followed below link to configure postgres in Linux,
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-postgresql-install-and-configure-from-source/

Please let me know it is not sufficient or if you can provide more details it would be helpful for me.

Comment: You downloaded the sources and compiled Postgres? Why didn't you install Postgres from RedHat? This might even help you to configure Postgres. For more information check the Postgres website (http://www.postgresql.org/).

Comment: Adjust pg_hba.conf for your new user.

Answer (score 0):

First try to be more specific:

- Which version of RHEL are you using?
- Which version of Windows are you using?
- How are these computers connected?

  - Are they in the same network segment?
  - Are there any firewalls in between

Next, try the following:

- Check firewall configurations

  - Windows firewall configuration (or any Antivirus/Firewall software that may be blocking the pgAdmin)
  - SELinux configuration and/or any antivirus/firewall that may be preventing connections to the linux host
  - If the host is a 'hostname' then check that the network services is translating the name correctly. Try a ping to the IP and then ping to the hostname. Or issue a dnslookup.
- In the linux system try **netstat -a | grep LISTEN |grep "5432"** to verify that there is a process actively LISTENING on port 5432

Hope this helps you to start solving your problem.

Comment: RHEL Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
Windows: Windows 7 Ultimate
Connecting using VPN
Firewall -- OFF

Firewall set to off on both Linux & Windows
I've tried both with IP & hostname of the VM.

Comment: OK. Is the VPN firewall allowing the app going through? Is the port open (5432)?

Comment: Firewall is disabled.

Comment: Are the systems in the same local network? Use the last command posted in the answer, please and check for a LISTENING process in the Postgres port